# Why can't I win gym battles?

Tags: pokemon-go

Ever since Niantic increased the spawn rate of rare Pokémon, it seems like most gyms I find are protected by a Snorlax. When I battle these gyms; even when the gym only has one Pokémon, I tend to run out of time during the battle.

I try to select Pokémon that will give me type advantage, and do my best to dodge attacks.  Despite my best efforts, I always seem to run out of time before I can win.

Am I playing wrong?  Should I simply spam attacks, and not worry about all my Pokémon getting knocked out?

As an example, a recent gym was protected by a 1900 CP Snorlax, and I was attacking with 1200 - 1300 CP Pokémon with fighting moves. My attacks were "super effective", but I was still unable to widdle down the Snorlax before time ran out.

Comment: spam your attacks, dodge their big attacks.

Comment: For high hp pokemon like snorlax and the one starting with C (I forget, chansey or clefable, one of the two) you may need to just continously attack instead of dodging their fast attacks, still probably worth it to dodge the charge attack if you can. Also depending, it may also be worth it to not use your charge attack, I've found a lot of the time, spamming the fast attack does more damage than using the charge attack when it's ready.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

High CP Snorlax are in gyms specifically because they do have the ability to outlast whole teams of lower CP attackers.  You need to make a compromise with them; if you have most of your team of pokémon left, then it's time to attack full bore and not worry about dodging.

If it's going to be closer, then you should pay attention for the super attacks and dodge those, but let the rest of the attacks go through, unless you're using Jolteon or one of the other high speed Pokémon who can afford to dodge without losing very many attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same trouble with *Snorlax*. What I did was got lucky and evolved a *Vileplume* with a `solar beam`. I keep its CP maxed. Now it is CP-1765. 3 or 4 hits with that `solar beam` has knocked down every *Snorlax* I've met so far.

You will eventually get lucky with an evolved pokemon that has `hyper beam` or `solar beam`. When you do, go all-in (even if it has poor HP ROI) with all the stardust you have. My *Vileplume* only has HP-109 so its not a good multi-use pokemon, but it is my *Snorlax* antidote.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are focusing too much on dodging attacks. Trying to dodge anything other than ultimate attacks is usually not worth it. Also in case of Snorlax, you should forget about type advantage because fighting Pokémon/moves are not really good in Pokémon Go.

Since you have 1200 - 1300 CP Pokémon, I expect you to own at least one Vaporeon. Try fighting with it. It can take almost as much damage as Snorlax and it can dish out a lot of damage itself. Or you can try other easily obtainable Pokémon such as Flareon, Jolteon, Golduck, Clefable, Dewgong, etc. Even when the Snorlax has much more CP, with 2-3 Pokémon you should be able to take him down.